# Inclusion exclusion - probability

Tags: probability, inclusion-exclusion

8 cards are drawn randomly from a pack of cards (52) with no returns.
We define these events:
S - not getting spade in those 8 cards
H - not getting heart in those 8 cards
D - ''  ''  diamond '' '' ''
C - '' '' Clubs '' '' ''

What is the probability at least one card from each series is in the cards chosen (e.g. there is at least one heart, at least one club at least one spade and at least one diamond)?

[image: Picture of the answers]

Comment: Since this is multiple choice, the difficulty of finding the numerator was taken away from you... it will be $4\binom{39}{8}-6\binom{26}{8}+4\binom{13}{8}$, seen directly via inclusion-exclusion.  Now... the only differences between the answers in the multiple choice was whether we should subtract away from $1$... and whether we should be dividing by $52!$ or dividing by $\binom{52}{8}$...  Think about these for a moment... in what situation would we want to subtract away from $1$?  Do we want to subtract away from $1$ here?  In what situation would we want to divide by $52!$?  Do we want to?

Comment: Recall, $P(A)=1-P(A^c)$ and $52!$ is the number of ways of ordering a deck of $52$ cards while $\binom{52}{8}$ is the number of "different" (*order not mattering*) eight-card hands, each of which are equally likely to occur.

Comment: @JMoravitz so the second answer is correct? because we dont want to subtract it from one and we want to divide by the number of ways to choose 8 cards and not to "shuffle" the whole deck am i right?

Comment: "*Because we don't want to subtract it from one*"  What makes you say that?  What does the calculation $4\binom{39}{8}-6\binom{26}{8}+4\binom{13}{8}$ represent in the first place?  Don't just guess and use process of elimination here... actually try to understand so that you can get it right the first time on the next time you see a similar problem.  Defining the events $S,H,D,C$ as above where each corresponds to having *not* drawn any of the corresponding cards of that suit, how might one go about calculating $Pr(S\cup H\cup D\cup C)$ or $|S\cup H\cup D\cup C|$?

Comment: What does the event $S\cup H\cup D\cup C$ represent in the first place?  How does $Pr(S\cup H\cup D\cup C)$ correspond to the probability that we are actually interested in, the probability that there is at least one card from each suit in our hand?

Comment: @JMoravitz I can tell that it is some form of pascals triangle 4 6 4 and it something about inclusion exclusion the + - + but I cant tell why its this specific numbers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability we are interested in is the probability that in our hand we *do* have at least one spade **and** we *do* have at least one heart as well as at least one club and at least one diamond.

If we were to let $S,H,C,D$ be as defined above as the events that we do *not* have a card of the corresponding type in our hand, we are wanting to calculate $Pr(S^c\cap H^c\cap C^c\cap D^c)$, i.e. the probability that it is *not* the case that we have no spades as well as it is *not* the case that we have no hearts, etc...

So... to approach, we do this by looking at the opposite event.  $(S^c\cap H^c\cap C^c\cap D^c)^c$ which simplifies as $S\cup H\cup C\cup D$, seen by De Morgan's Laws.

Now, the probability $Pr(S\cup H\cup C\cup D)$ can be calculated via inclusion-exclusion as $$Pr(S)+Pr(H)+Pr(C)+Pr(D)-Pr(S\cap H)-Pr(S\cap C)\dots - Pr(C\cap D) + Pr(S\cap H\cap C)+\dots Pr(H\cap C\cap D) - Pr(S\cap H\cap C\cap D)$$

Recognizing the symmetry of the problem, that $Pr(S)=Pr(H)=Pr(C)=Pr(D)$ and $Pr(S\cap H)=Pr(S\cap C)=\dots = Pr(C\cap D)$ and so on... and that there are $4$ ways to write a single set by itself, $\binom{4}{2}=6$ ways to write two sets intersected, $\binom{4}{3}=4$ ways to write the intersection of three sets, etc... this simplifies further as:

$$4\cdot Pr(S)-6\cdot Pr(S\cap H)+4\cdot Pr(S\cap H\cap C) - Pr(S\cap H\cap C\cap D)$$

Now... to calculate the probability $Pr(S)$, this is the probability that among our eight cards, *none* of them were spades.  There are $39$ non-spade cards of which we want to pick eight of them to be used in our hand.  Dividing by $\binom{52}{8}$, the number of eight-card hands possible, and noting that each of those eight-card hands are equally likely to occur, gives us the probability $$Pr(S)=\dfrac{\binom{39}{8}}{\binom{52}{8}}$$

Similarly, $Pr(S\cap H)$ is the probability that among our eight cards none of them were hearts as well as none of them were spades.  There are $26$ non-heart non-spade cards of which we choose eight of them... giving $$Pr(S\cap H) = \dfrac{\binom{26}{8}}{\binom{52}{8}}$$

Continue in this fashion and recognize that it is impossible to have none of any of hearts spades clubs diamonds since having at least one card in hand automatically implies that we have at least one of those suits present, so the final term was zero and can be left out.

This all together gives us:

$$Pr(S\cup H\cup C\cup D) = \dfrac{4\binom{39}{8}-6\binom{26}{8}+4\binom{13}{8}}{\binom{52}{8}}$$

Remember though that $Pr(S\cup H\cup C\cup D)$ is not the actual probability we are interested in, but rather is the opposite probability of what we are interested in.  The probability we were actually interested in is:

$$Pr(S^c\cap H^c\cap C^c\cap D^c) = 1 - Pr(S\cup H\cup C\cup D) = 1 - \dfrac{4\binom{39}{8}-6\binom{26}{8}+4\binom{13}{8}}{\binom{52}{8}}$$

Comment: You are amazing sir, thank you for the explicit answer !